# performSegue - does it stop further code execution?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, runloop

Does the call performSegue supposed to stop further code execution and pass execution to the target?

I have this simple call :
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTweets", sender: self)
But seems like the following code after that line is still executing...
Is that normal?

Comment: Yes, that is normal.

Comment: It's normal. But why are you executing code after? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 8):

No, it won't stop further execution. The actual segue transition will happen *when* you return control to the main run loop (e.g., return from a `@IBAction` marked callback method).

Comment: so should I check with a flag to prevent further code from executing? whats the best way to handle it?

Comment: The common approach is just to return/exit from the function calling `performSegue`. A common idiom is to call `performSegue` as your last statement, so an explicit `return` may not even be necessary.